# Is it possible to use profile sync on two a production and staging sharepoint server?

Tags: active-directory, profile-sync, production, staging

Our staging server has been neglected for a while, and I'm trying to get it back to as close as production as I can. I'm trying to setup profile sync and I've used the same accounts for production and I'm not pulling any accounts back.

We don't use profile sync to export back to AD so I figured using the synchronization service wasn't necessary. After not getting any accounts back I switched it to use the sync service and still no results.

EDIT: The ultimate goal would be to get staging setup without profile sync service, since from what I've read the service is not required if you never export back to AD, and eventually setup production the same way.

Comment: You should delete the existing User Profile service from Staging and start over. There is no harm in reusing the service accounts.

Comment: It's hard to pin point what it is doing. Is there a way to track the service and see why it's not pulling anything?

Comment: You can start the profile sync and then check the log files.

Comment: What would the event be under?

Comment: Are you connecting to same AD domain in both Prod & Staging? What i understand, you want to use same services account for the both Farm's User Profile Sync Services, correct?

Comment: Yes, and they are both on the same domain. I've not had a lot of experience with this service which is why I'm running into a lot of trouble. I'm also not a domain admin so I can't really delve into that area for troubleshooting without calling someone. Starting to become a rabbit hole, because I stopped the sync on production so I could look at the connection settings, and now it's being stubborn trying to get it started again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving too much information so helping is quite difficult. UPS can be broken in million different ways, but looks like the sync is starting but it's not importing anything.

Look at FIM console for the specific error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe` --> verify you're not missing Replicate Directory permission in AD for the UPS sync account. If the error is something else, let us know.

[image]

Comment: It turns out the account I was using to perform the sync was not the correct one. A similar account had been created before me and switching this resolved the sync issue. Thanks for point me in the right direction.